# Once a solution has been found in lambda calculus, how easy is it to convert this to code?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lisp, lambda-calculus

If you were to read a problem statement, such as something found on TopCoder, and you converted it to a lambda calculus representation, is it a simple exercise to 'convert' this to Haskell or Lisp code?

In other words, can a problem be solved using the lambda calculus formal system and then trivially implemented in a functional programming language?

Comment: I believe (but can't / won't prove) it would be trivial to translate any program written in the simply typed lambda calculus to Haskell (there are functions you can write in the untyped lambda calculus that you can't write in Haskell). Glasgow Haskell desugars to SystemF - which roughly speaking is a more powerful version of the simply typed lambda calculus - so Haskell "includes" the STLC already. Your translation would just have to convert to a tiny subset of Haskell that is unsugared - naturally the result would be very verbose and not idiomatic.

Comment: @stephentetley: In fact there's nothing to prove. The translation is very trivial, `λx:τ. M` is translated to `\(x :: τ) -> M` and a function application `M N` remains the same. The problem arises with untyped lambda calculus, since there are terms which cannot be typed without rolling/unrolling infinite types (very nice example is the `Y` combinator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for Haskell is quite similar to the lambda calculus. Your problem is going to be that some terms in the untyped lambda calculus won't be accepted by Haskell's type checker.

Out of curiosity, who *the hell* solves TopCoder using the lambda calculus? *That* sounds highly non-trivial. o_O

Comment: so in that sense Lisp might be simpler to translate to, because it is also untyped?

Comment: I have high-level (unconscious) thoughts in my sleep. My cat woke me up at 3am and this is what bled through into my conscious. I heard the question in my head and began considering using lambda calculus as an intermediate representation of a problem. I would do this because it could allow the conversion of a verbose problem statement into something purely symbolic. The result of this would ideally be a simple, stripped-to-the-bone computational problem, and not a high-level description. Essentially, the purpose is reduction of a 'real-world' system into a mathematical/computational one.

Comment: `(λnmfx. n(mf)x)(λfx. f(fx))(λfx. f(fx))` is a really, _really_ wordy way to say `2 + 2`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That's a difficult question.  In theory, yes.  In practice, sort of.  In general, I would say that defined computable functions can be efficiently-implemented (in the time-space of programmer effort), yes, but it really depends on the familiarity with the programming language and the mathematics in question over the possibility of doing so.  For example, I suppose one could implement a lambda calculus interpreter, and I direct you to ['Visual Automata Simulator]'[1](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~jbovet/vas.html) for an example of Turing's model contained in a trivializing wrapper.

Comment: "I suppose one could implement a lambda calculus interpreter" - yes, quite easily. The untyped lambda calculus is the first in a series of increasingly complex languages which are presented in Types and Programming Languages. Implementations are in OCaml: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/

Comment: The introduction to that book: "A type system is a syntactic method for enforcing levels of abstraction in programs." FAIL!